# How to show dropdown options in fluent UI breadcrumbs

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, fluent-ui

i wanted to show dropdown in fluent ui breadcrumbs help on building the code. please refer below image

[Reference image copied from azure devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJZ6Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

To show the dropdown menu at breadcrumbs, you need **CommandBarButton** as the trigger of the dropdown and **menuProps** that contain the menu's item objects and pass the **CommandBarButton** at **Breadcrumb's** last item **onRenderContent** event handler.

Don't forget to memoize both breadcrumb's items and dropdown menuProps.

```js
  import { CommandBarButton } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Button";
  ...

  const menuProps: IContextualMenuProps = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          key: "def",
          text: "Dev",
          onClick: () => setEnvironment("Dev"),
          onRenderContent: () => {
            return <MenuItem label="Dev" environment={environment} />;
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    };
  }, [environment, setEnvironment]);

  const items: IBreadcrumbItem[] = React.useMemo(() => {
    return [
      { text: "Files", key: "Files", onClick: _onBreadcrumbItemClicked },
      { text: "Folder 1", key: "f1", onClick: _onBreadcrumbItemClicked },
      ...
      { text: "Folder 6", key: "f6", onClick: _onBreadcrumbItemClicked },
      {
        text: "Folder 11",
        key: "f11",
        onClick: _onBreadcrumbItemClicked,
        isCurrentItem: true,
        onRenderContent: () => {
          return (
            <CommandBarButton
              style={{
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: "30px",
                padding: 0,
                background: "transparent"
              }}
              text={environment}
              iconProps={null}
              disabled={false}
              checked={false}
              menuProps={menuProps}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    ];
  }, [environment, menuProps]);
```

This is the complete code:

[image: Edit sharp-kowalevski-d5e3pe]